# Use of undefined constant DIR_INCLUDE after redirect

Tags: php, header, constants

I have wriiten a index.php in my root directory(i.e. classroom folder in my case).which is supposed to be the only entry path of my website.

first few lines of my index.php is

index.php

```
<?php
     include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classroom/include/db.inc.php' ;
     session_start();
     define('BASE_URL', '/classroom/');
     define('DIR_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
     define('DIR_HOME', DIR_ROOT . 'home' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
     define('DIR_INCLUDE', DIR_ROOT . 'include' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
     if(isset($_GET['name']) and $_GET['name'] == 'home' )
     {
          $url='';
          $url= BASE_URL . 'home' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
          header("Location: $url");
          exit();
     }
```

now in home directory it will load the home.html.php.now when am try to use 'DIR_HOME' or 'DIR_INCLUDE'.its showing a error message

> ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_INCLUDE - assumed
>   'DIR_INCLUDE' in C:\wamp\www\classroom\home\home.html.php on line 17

i am giving you the portion where the error occurred in my home.html.php

home.html.php

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4px" >
<tr>
 <td>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td class="top">
                <?php include(DIR_INCLUDE . 'topper.html.php') ; ?> 
        </td>
    </tr>
```

the problem is solved when i am including home.html.php in my index.php.but then its not following the url like localhost/classroom/home its always remaining as localhost/classroom.

QUESTION :why this error is coming??how to solve it by keeping the url like localhost/classroom/home

**EDIT: i think there is some misinterpretation.my question is how can i solve the problem while it will keep the url as localhost/clasroom/home...and if i include all dir definition in every script then same way i will alsso be needed to include session_start() in every script..my question is if i do so will it then hold single entry path concept**.because i want to maintain the single entry path

Comment: Because `home.php` is a distinct script, where you did indeed not define the constant. It doesn't magically carry over after a redirection.

Comment: then according to you i have to include the file home.php.but please watch my question ...i knew it...my question was how can i solve it by making the url like localhost/classroom/home...because when i am using include the url doesnt change..it remains same like  localhost/classroom

Comment: Put all constant declarations in a separate script, include from output templates.

Comment: i have got that idea...but then my question is .....will it then follow single entry path concept????..i think no

Comment: because the concept behind single entry path is putting all necessary command like session_start() or including db conn in one script

Comment: if i include the directory definitions in all script then same way i will need to include session_start() also in all scripts which will need it..right???....then i think it will break single entry path concept..right??

Comment: Elaborate on your dispatcher script and RewriteRules then instead of adding obnoxious bold text. Your single entry script `index.php` doesn't get applied obviously.

Comment: `RewriteRules` didnt understand @mario

Comment: One last tip (this seems too much tutoring and chat): you ought to include the templates with `include()`, not `header()` reredirect there - if `index.php` is really a request handler.

Comment: but it will change the url then..i want localhost/classroom/home

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're mixing responsibilities. `index.php` should not contain bootstrap events, including that constant definitions.

`bootstrapper` should always be separated file, in most cases it should define only common constants and init common variables as well.

```
 <?php

 /* File : bootstrap.php */

 include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classroom/include/db.inc.php' ;

 session_start();

 define('BASE_URL', '/classroom/');
 define('DIR_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
 define('DIR_HOME', DIR_ROOT . 'home' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
 define('DIR_INCLUDE', DIR_ROOT . 'include' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Your `index.php`

```
 <?php

 require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/bootstrap.php');

 if(isset($_GET['name']) and $_GET['name'] == 'home' )
 {
      $url='';
      $url= BASE_URL . 'home' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
      header("Location: $url");
      exit();
 }
```

And your `home.html.php`

```
<?php require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/bootstrap.php'); ?>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4px" >
<tr>
 <td>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td class="top">
                <?php include(DIR_INCLUDE . 'topper.html.php') ; ?> 
        </td>
    </tr>
```

That's just a demonstration to make it work. In real-world you should not code this way. Learn about `SOLID` principles, `OOP` and `MVC`